# How do you delete an SSAS cube?

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

According to [this](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174802(v=sql.105).aspx) you can only delete Databases (or do I read it in an incorrect way?) even if the name of the page suggests cubes can be deleted.

There is no Cube type objects on Server manager Studio either.

Trying to delete the files directly from .../MSAS11.Mydatabase/Olap/Data doesn't work because they are open by some system process.

But we have created several test solutions with their cubes that we would like to delete so users accessing the service don't see them.

How can we delete them?

Edited to add image:

[image: SSMS options]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can delete a database or a cube. 
To delete a cube using script:

```
<Delete xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
  <Object>
    <DatabaseID>YourDBName</DatabaseID>
    <CubeID>a85a8467-0c9a-475f-a903-a38d57ff7030</CubeID>
  </Object>
</Delete>
```

or by using SSMS
[image]

Comment: Seems I must be missing something, I have no Cubes options on SSMS. Added image to original post.

Comment: Ahhhhhh forget it! Found ... I was connecting to wrong service! Thanks